# WinApi, hide cursor inside window client area

Tags: winapi

I want hide cursor inside window client area without borders and title bar (it is simple opengl application). So, function

```
    ShowCursor(FALSE);
```

is not suitable. After some searching the winapi i find this solution:

```
    //when create window class for application window
    WNDCLASSEX WndClass;
    //...
    BYTE CursorMaskAND[] = { 0xFF };
    BYTE CursorMaskXOR[] = { 0x00 };
    WndClass.hCursor = CreateCursor(NULL, 0,0,1,1, CursorMaskAND, CursorMaskXOR);
```

Is this a good way to solve this typical task? What way is the best?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSDN says that you can set the WNDCLASSEX hCursor field to NULL, in which case you must explicitly set the cursor in your window procedure (which means handling the WM_SETCURSOR message). For example:

```
if (Msg == WM_SETCURSOR && LOWORD(lParam) == HTCLIENT)
{
    SetCursor(NULL);

    return TRUE;
}

// Remainder of window procedure code
```

Checking for HTCLIENT ensures that the cursor is only hidden in the client area, and that the window frame and caption will use the correct cursors.

Answer (score 0):

The SetCursor() call you're using doesn't take a BOOL - it takes an HCURSOR. So you're calling SetCursor( NULL ) which means "hide that cursor". What I found in the old days on Windows is that this is video driver dependent and many drivers don't respect it. The most consistent way to handle this is to make a transparent cursor resource in your app, and return a handle to that cursor in the WM_SETCURSOR message from your main window.

Comment: Check this link out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648391(v=VS.85).aspx for loading a cursor... other than that not sure what you need?

Comment: I meant a driver behaviour with SetCursor(NULL) you point. I just want to know how is it actual.

Comment: That wasn't intended as a typical case, it's just the sure-fire way to work around any driver errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found that first setting `hCursor` to `NULL`:

```
    wc.hCursor = NULL;
```

and then setting the cursor to `NULL`:

```
    SetCursor(NULL);
```

will make it disappear.

From MSDN, I read that the application will set its own cursor by default if one is not defined in `hCursor`. That's what the first line of code is doing.

Then, after the application sets its own cursor, I mess with it with the second line of code. Or at least, I think that's what happens.